# Lan and baseband channel

Tags: ethernet, networking, lan

We know the baseband line at one time send or receive data(half duplex). If more than one host send data at same time may occur collision. In bus topology see the same thing. Inspite this in home, college, university uses this lan technologies. But there doesn't occurred any collision and they did multiple task parallelly.
My question is that what is the actual reason to not occurred collision after using LAN(ring topology) in (home, college, university)?

Comment: Modern ethernet uses switching on UTP (different send and receive paths) for full duplex. It is still baseband. We no longer have shared coax that has the same send and receive path (collisions). You still get collisions on Wi-Fi because it uses a shared medium, but a host cannot detect the collisions, so it uses CSMA/CA to try to avoid collisions instead of CSMA/CD to detect collisions.

Comment: @Ron Maupin could modern Ethernet use *statistical TDM* to avoid collision?

Comment: No. It simply has separate send and receive paths on dedicated, switched links so that there are no collisions.

Comment: Yes, of course. Basically, baseband means that the signal uses the entire bandwidth of the path, while broadband uses a portion so that there can be simultaneous signals that do not interfere with each other (like cable television).

Comment: @RonMaupin "Basically, baseband means that the signal uses the entire bandwidth of the path"---modern baseband are full duplex, so how it use full bandwidth, it will be shared by another source-destination pairs?

Comment: Full duplex has different paths for send and receive. Either separate physical paths, separate frequencies, or special noise and echo cancellation. It greatly depends on the specific implementation.

Comment: @RonMaupin full duplex has different path for text, image, audio, video for sending and 4 similar receiving path. Mean there are 4 pairs? Am I correct?

Comment: No, it does not know or care about the content. A classic example id 100Base-TX ethernet that has one pair for send and one pair for receive, regardless if the data carried on each. All received data comes in on the receive pair, and all sent data goes out the send pair. You should really ask this type of question on [electronics.se]. because it gets very technical very fast, and it is not something that network engineers normally deal with.

Comment: @RonMaupin "broadband uses a portion so that there can be simultaneous signals that do not interfere with each other "--- in broadband has one pair where one wire for sending and other for receiving. You mean text, audio, video both uses different portion of bandwidth? What do u mean bandwidth portion?

Comment: Broadband is like your cable television. You have multiple signals (channels) that all simultaneously travel over one wire, but use different frequencies.

Comment: @RonMaupin cable television is full duplex? Only signal is coming(sending) for different signal but how signal is coming from TV? It uses one wire or one pair of wire?

Comment: Yes, it actually is full duplex. For example, my Internet connection that I am using right now is over the same cable for my television. DOCSIS defines two-way communication on cable. In fact, if you use the cable box to order pay-per-view, it sends a signal back to the cable company. The system is now complaining about all the comments. You should really taker this to [electronics.se].

Comment: @RonMaupin suppose 4 hosts connected to switch which has 4 different wires.And switch is connected to router by one wire. Now if 2 hosts want to transmit the at the same time then via switch then switch to router link treated as baseband or broadband?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Baseband* is a 'plain' signaling method (in contrast to using one or more carrier frequencies), entirely unrelated to the access method in a network.

What you're referring to is *CSMA/CD* used with early Ethernet. CSMA/CD is practically extinct with micro-segmented, fully-switched networks utilizing full duplex being the norm (due to switches having supplanted primitive repeater hubs, or even the early shared-wire technology used with coax). There are no collisions on full-duplex links.

Ethernet generally uses a star or tree (=multi-star) topology. Rings or chains should generally be avoided for performance and reliability reasons.